# How do I get SQL to talk to an Oracle (or other vendor) database in Beaker notebook?

Tags: beaker-notebook

How do I get SQL to talk to an Oracle database? Do I need the JDBC driver JAR from Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Get the JDBC driver JAR from the vendor, and add a path to it to the class path in the settings for SQL in the Language manager.